# gae datastore composite index rebuild / update for new entities

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, composite-index

I'm using GAE Datastore composite index and successfully created composite index 2 days ago. The index is in "serving" state. However the index is not automatically updated for new entries. Do I have to wait for it to be updated automatically, or I have to manually trigger with `gcloud preview datastore create-indexes INDEX_FILE [GLOBAL-FLAG …]` command? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entities will be automatically indexed, there is no need to manual create/run anything once you have created the composite index.

**Note:** The individual properties in the entity *cannot* be flagged as 'unindexed' if you want them in the composite index. This is because composite indexes require the individual property to be indexed as well.